# Setting css properties with SASS and :nth-child

Tags: css, sass

I have about 600 lines of code that repeats itself to set the background position of an image sprite to display a bunch of images.

```
  #foo-label {
    background-position: (1 * -96) + px 0;
    &:hover {
      background-position: (1 * -96) + px -192px;
    }
  }

  #bar-label {
    background-position: (2 * -96) + px 0;
    &:hover {
      background-position: (2 * -96) + px -192px;
    }
  }

...
```

Is it possible using SASS to use something like the :nth-child selector to determine the index of the selected element and set its background position as a multiple of that index? Such as;

```
  #images-parent label:nth-child(index) {
    background-position: (index * -96) + px 0;
    &:hover {
      background-position: (index * -96) + px -192px;
    }
  }
```

I just read about mixins, which will cut the code in less than half since I can now do this;

```
@mixin img-position($index) {
  background-position: ($index * -96) + px -96px;
  &:hover {
    background-position: ($index * -96) + px -96px;
  }
}

#foo-label {
  @include img-position(1);
}
```

I still need to set this for each individual label though, so still wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: How do you think that could possibly work when Sass only compiles to CSS, and is never sent to the user?

Comment: I'm not sure. All I know is that my current solution is not maintainable. I came here to learn how others would solve this problem.

Comment: @cimmanon Well it turns out it is possible since that duplicate question is the exact answer I was looking for. Your attitude is not appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what my solution looks like using mixins. 600+ lines of code down to 90.

```
$unchecked: 0;
$checked: -96;
$hover: -192;

@mixin img-position($index, $state) {
  background-position: ($index * -96) + px $state + px;
  &:hover {
    background-position: ($index * -96) + px ($hover - $state) + px;
  }
}

input[type=checkbox],
input[type=radio] {
  &.img-checkbox {
    position:absolute;
    left:-3000px;

    &.checked + #bars-label                   { @include img-position(0, $checked); }
    &.checked + #event_spaces-label           { @include img-position(1, $checked); }
    &.checked + #night_clubs-label            { @include img-position(2, $checked); }

    + label {
      background-image:url('img.jpg');
      height: 96px;
      width: 96px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
      cursor:pointer;

      &#bars-label                   { @include img-position(0, $unchecked); }
      &#event_spaces-label           { @include img-position(1, $unchecked); }
      &#night_clubs-label            { @include img-position(2, $unchecked); }
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone has any improvements or feedback please let me know!